# Add-on cards disabled M.2 SSD slot of Asus Prime B350M-A motherboard

Tags: ssd, motherboard, pci-express, nvme, m.2

Need help from experienced rig builders. I am using KingSpec 512Gb NVMe SSD on M.2 onboard slot, it ran fine for one month. Yesterday I tried to plug another SSD of the same model through expansion card on PCIe x16 slot. After a boot computer did not recognise any of two SSDs - no old, neither new one. I turned it off, took out expansion card, rebooted and on-board M.2 SSD came alive again.

Today I tried to use another add-on card to x1 PCIe slot and switched to it two new SATA III SSDs (disk manager found them well and I’ve assigned letters to them). After that I turned PC off, plugged them off entirely together with add-on card and ran system again. But this time BIOS and Win 10 Disk Manager did not see my PCIe SSD in M.2 slot. I tried another new PCIe SSD after that and it failed too. What’s wrong? It’s the same hardware configuration, which worked fine yesterday. How can I troubleshoot M.2 port and get it back alive again? BIOS settings were not changed since last run, when M.2 slot worked fine.

Configuration of my PC:

- MB: Asus Prime B350M-A, BIOS-4207
- OS: Windows 10 64 bit
- Graphics: nVIDIA GeForce GT 710
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 1700X
- Memory: Hynix, PC4-19200
  16GB*4, DDR4, 2400MHz
- SSD for M.2 PCIe NVMe: KingSpec NE-512

Add-on cards (took off all of them):

- NVMe M.2 SSD to PCI x16 converter: JEYI JY-3SD ver:1.5 8J25
- SATA III to PCI x1 converter: Gudga PCE4SAT-M01
- PCIe 16x Graphics to PCIe 1x converter: AC3137

Comment: both disks appeared alive. have tested them on another rig. tomorrow will try under Prime again with battery removal for  bios reset

Comment: battery removal and switching sata cables from top to side slots of PCIe x1 add-on card helped: NVMe SSD in the on-board M.2 slot is operational again

Comment: the only question left: is there any reliable add-on card for NVMe M.2 to PCIe x16 slot that would work with Asus Prime B350M-A mobo? Does it support any M.2 extantion?

Comment: Reply of Asus support: Only our such card is guaranteed compatible: https://www.asus.com/Motherboard-Accessories/HYPER_M2_X4_MINI_CARD/ This does not mean that the rest are incompatible, most likely 99% of these cards are compatible, since this is just an adapter, but only you can verify this, by yourself.